# Data source always returns full data from room data base even if I provided the amount of data loaded each page

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-paging

I am using paging (part of android Jetpack ) to retrieve data from my room DB. I wanted to fetch 50 records on each page. But  'DataSource.Factory.toLivedata(pageSize)' function returning full data from the database.

I have tried providing configuration for toLivedata() method but seems like its ignored

```
private val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setInitialLoadSizeHint(50)
        .setPageSize(50)
        .build()

fun getPagedData(): LiveData<PagedList<TransactionEntity>> =
        transactionDao.getAllTransactions().toLiveData(config)

//TransctionDao
@Query("SELECT * FROM transaction_table order by date DESC")
    fun getAllTransactions(): DataSource.Factory<Int, TransactionEntity>

//Observing Live Data
getPagedData().observe(this,Observer<PagedList<TransactionEntity>> { t ->
            Log.d("Activity", "Size is " + t.size)

})
```

I was expecting the size of PagedList as 50, but its always giving entire records from transaction_table

Comment: How many rows do you have in your DB at the moment? And how do you know it loaded more than 50?

Comment: I have over 7000+ (dummy data) rows in the table. And inside the observer, I just checked the PagedList's size and it was more than 7000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you think all the data is loaded is that PagedList uses placeholders for data that was not yet loaded and so as in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList.html#size()) the size represents the whole data size and not just the loaded data size.

If you want to change this you can use `setEnablePlaceholders(false)` in the config builder. You can test it by calling `get(6500)` and you should get null as this item was not loaded yet.

I advise you to read the [PlaceHolders](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList.html#placeholders) section.

Comment: Thanks, @Itamar Kertbel for the crisp and clear explanation. I just tested it and worked as expected. Marking this as the accepted answer.